# Python cryptocurrency | CCXT.ftx().fetch_my_trades() KeyError "Symbol"

Tags: python, keyerror, ccxt

I use the CCXT module to communicate with multiple cryptocurrency exchanges. However when trying to request my trades or other orders I get the error "Key error symbol" even tho i use a Valid symbol and other functions work.

Code :

```
cftx = ccxt.ftx({"apiKey":ftx_keys.api,
          "secret":ftx_keys.secret})
print(cftx.fetch_my_trades(symbol="BTC-PERP",limit=100))
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ccxt\ftx.py", line 564, in parse_trade
    symbol = market['symbol']
KeyError: 'symbol'
```

I have tried other symbols and markets but without succses

Comment: I think you should change `BTC-PERP` to `BTC/PERP`

Comment: I understand the logic behind that but sadly ennough that does not work
They use / for spot markets and - for futures, I tried it with multiple pairs that I pulled from FTX themselves.

Still thx a lot for the input!

Comment: Well it is possible that `ftx` exchange does not contain your desired key.

Comment: I would say your right but they have the key since I got it from the api itself + im trading bitcoin right now

A cryptocurrency exchange that focusses on BTC futures will have btc lol

Comment: @Python_Noob you might want to check what's going on in verbose mode:
https://gist.github.com/kroitor/88ad0b11898f4eb8dfdc9cb66a73aadb
Make a gist with the output and paste a link to it here (strip your credentials from the output if you want).

Answer (score 3):

You should call `load_markets()` before trying to fetch anything related to markets.

Change your code like below:

```py
cftx = ccxt.ftx({"apiKey":ftx_keys.api,
          "secret":ftx_keys.secret})
markets = cftx.load_markets()
print(cftx.fetch_my_trades(symbol="BTC-PERP",limit=100))
```

Comment: Yes that how I load my market data to get the symbol, however it simply gives the same error (your code).  All my data is from the api itself, Keys are correct cus with works when I try to get my balance.

Comment: That's weird. I have no problem calling `fetch_my_trades` with the exact same parameters. /shrug works on my machine!